# Efficient method of multiplying two non-sparse matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices of type float:
 `A` whose dimensions are 7000x100000 and
 `B` whose dimensions are 100000x20.
When I multiply them my code consumes my entire RAM even though the output is small.
Is there a way to make this more memory efficient?
I tried doing [this from Matlab help page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19871-large-matrix-multiplication-and-out-of-memory-error-in-matlab) but it did not help.

Comment: Do the matrices have the same numeric type?  Maybe if `A` is an integer type but `B` is a floating-point type then there's some implicit conversion of `A` to floating-point going on—that would take up more memory than expected.    I'm a little confused about whether your matrices are sparse or not.  Tag says `sparse-matrix` but title says non-sparse.

Comment: Both are float. I'm sorry I should've mentioned that

Comment: can you hold both matrices `A` and `B` in memory before multiplying them? do you get "out of mem" only when you are trying to multiply?

Comment: I can hold them in memory. In fact, I can even multiply 2000x100000 and 100000x20 matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and divide into blocks:

**By rows of `A`:**

```
row_blk = 1000;
C = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,2), class(A));
f = 1; t = row_blk;
while t <= size(A,1)
   C(f:t,:) = A(f,t,:)*B;
   f = t+1;
   t = min(size(A,1), f+row_blk-1);
end
```

**By columns of `A`:**

```
col_blk = 10000;
C = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,2), class(A));
f = 1; t = col_blk;
while t <= size(A,2)
    C = C + A(:,f:t)*B(f:t,:);
    f = t+1;
    t = min(size(A,2), f+col_blk-1);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I run this code in GNU Octave and  memory consumpton of this code:

```
a= rand(7000,100000);
b = rand(100000,20);
```

is:

```
Absolute running time: 10.05 sec, cpu time: 9.97 sec, memory peak: 5375 Mb
```

and memory consumption of this code:

```
a= rand(7000,100000);
b = rand(100000,20);
c = a * b;
```

is:

```
Absolute running time: 14.26 sec, cpu time: 14.19 sec, memory peak: 5376 Mb
```

so no significant difference observed!

Comment: Even creating the matrices takes up my RAM

Comment: @iLoveCamelCase As in other answer noted using a loop you can create partial matrices , multiply them ,save results and then continue with remaining part of matrices

Comment: I use 32-bit version of Octave. It is not possible to create matrix a(7000,100000). Error is - "error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type". So to work with such matrix you need 64-bit version of Matlab/Octave. Is your Octave 64-bit?

Comment: @SergV I tested it on rextester online Octave interpreter: http://rextester.com/l/octave_online_compiler